# How to pass along the results through elements in a list?

Tags: r, list, reduce

I have a list `TRADE`, which contains lots of data.frames. I need to perform the same data manipulation on each data.frames. Suppose this manipulation could be written in `FUNCTION(initial.value, dataframe...)`.

But I couldn't use `apply()` family because the initial.amount used by the FUNCTION on TRADE[[i+1]] is the final.amount computed by `FUNCTION` on `TRADE[[i]]`.

I was told `REDUCE()` function could pass intermediate results through list. I read several related examples but couldn't figure out how to use in my case.

A simplified example is provided below. Could anyone give some suggestions?

```
ACLS <- data.frame( TICKER = c("ACLS", "ACLS", "ACLS"), 
                    MIDQUOTE = c(11.05, 11.05, 11.05),
                    TradeSize = c(500, 153, 1247),
                    TradePrice = c(11.099, 11.080, 11.120) )
A <- data.frame( TICKER = c("A", "A", "A"), 
                 MIDQUOTE = c(37.075, 37.075, 37.075),
                 TradeSize = c(100, 1000, 500),
                 TradePrice = c(36.75, 36.00, 37.49) )
AAPL <- data.frame( TICKER = c("AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"), 
                    MIDQUOTE = c(23.56, 23.56, 23.56),
                    TradeSize = c(100, 100, 102),
                    TradePrice = c(23.600, 23.650, 23.650) )

TRADE <- list(ACLS, A, AAPL)
```

A separate data.frame CAPITAL to store values computed from TRADE:

```
CAPITAL <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(TRADE), ncol = 5))
names(CAPITAL) <- c("intial.amount","buy.amount","sell.amount","profit", "final.amount")
CAPITAL[1,1] <- 30000
```

Data manipulation procedure:

```
for(i in 1:length(TRADE)){
    initial.amount <- CAPITAL[i,1]
    buy.amount <- TRADE[[i]]$TradePrice[1]*TRADE[[i]]$TradeSize[1]
    sell.amount <- TRADE[[i]]$TradePrice[3]*TRADE[[i]]$TradeSize[3]
    profit <- sell.amount - buy.amount
    final.amount <- initial.amount  + profit
    record <- c(buy.amount, sell.amount, profit, final.amount)
    CAPITAL[i, 2:5] <- record
    CAPITAL[i+1, 1] <- CAPITAL[i, 5]
}
```

We can see from this loop the final.amount from `TRADE[[i]]` will be passed as the initial.amount for `TRADE[[i+1]]`. But how to do this with `REDUCE` or other non-loop functions?

The result I need is the `final.amount` column in the resulting `CAPITAL`:

```
|initial.amount|  buy.amount |  sell.amount | profit | final.amount
|:-------------|------------:|:------------:|:-------|:--------
| 30000.00     |      5549.5 |     13866.64 | 8317.14| 38317.14
| 38317.14     |      3675.0 |     18745.00 |15070.00| 53387.14
| 53387.14     |      2630.0 |      2412.30 |   52.30| 53439.44
| 53439.44     |          NA |           NA |      NA|       NA
```

Comment: Are you trying to compute something like `f(a[5],f(a[4],f(a[3],f(a[2],f(a[1],0))))))`?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes. Kind of like that. The computed value, final.amount, will be used as the initial.amount in the 2nd data frame. Then the final.amount computed from 2nd data frame will be used as the initial.value for the 3rd data.frame. But except this, all other operations are the same.

Comment: The `Reduce` function will carry forward intermediate results from sequential processing of lists. There are many worked examples in SO. (`sapply`, `vapply`, `mapply` and `lapply` do not support that procedure.)

Comment: @alistaire. I just provide a reproducible example. Is this example OK? Could you remove hold status if you are an administrator? Or do I need to close this question and open a new one. Thanks!

Comment: @alistaire Just edit. Do you have any suggestions on how I could use REDUCE or any functions to solve this?

Comment: @alistaire  It is totally reproducible now. I just need the final.amount column. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, you could just use `cumsum` here, which is a pre-assembled `Reduce` cousin. I'm not really convinced what you're doing makes sense, though; you're iterating over stocks instead of over time periods. Anyway, in dplyr it would be `library(dplyr); TRADE %>% bind_rows(.id = 'i') %>% group_by(i, TICKER) %>% summarise(profit = last(TradePrice) * last(TradeSize) - first(TradePrice) * first(TradeSize)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(final.amount = 30000 + cumsum(profit))`

Comment: @alistaire   Seems loop is easier. The function is made up by myself. Real one is kind of complex.

Comment: The problem is that loops become very slow if not implemented just so. Working with a single data.frame via grouping is a faster and safer route as you scale up.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant way but it works faster than the loop

```
buy.amount = sapply(TRADE, function(x) x[1,4]*x[1,3])
sell.amount = sapply(TRADE, function(x) x[3,4]*x[3,3])
profit = sell.amount-buy.amount
initial.amount = cumsum(c(30000,profit))
final.amount = initial.amount[-1]
```

in my PC your loop version takes 0.08 seconds and this takes 0.041. For the final matrix I don't think you need the last value of `initial.amount` so you can just remove it and bind all together